# CSS transform losing hover state on mouse move

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transforms

I have the following HTML/CSS mark-up which should transform the `div` element on `:hover` state.

When hovering over the `div` element, the `:hover` styles are added correctly. However on mouse move, these styles are lost, until the mouse stops moving.

Why is this happening?

---

**HTML:**

```
<div class="module">
sdfsdf
<br><br>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" />
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
.module
{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:blue;
    margin:10px;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
}

.module:hover
{
    -webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.08s;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    -webkit-transform:perspective(800px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) translateZ(-20px);

}​
```

---

[**-- See jsFiddle Demo --**](http://jsfiddle.net/nHaHw/2/)

Note: My demo and CSS is for webkit only at the moment.

I'm replicating this issue on Google Chrome Version 23.0.1271.95 m

Comment: Not for me, what browser are you using?

Comment: @Andy Google Chrome. This code has only been created for webkit so far

Comment: For me on chrome, it only happens when mousing down the top/left edges, but obviously that's because the element is moving in/out of mouse area. Is that your problem or can I not recreate it?

Comment: which version of chrome, it's ok for me too

Comment: I can't see any transformation using Chromium 20.

Comment: @khaled_webdev I'm replicating this issue on Google Chrome Version 23.0.1271.95 m

Comment: @feeela I'm replicating this issue on Google Chrome Version 23.0.1271.95 m

Comment: test from bottom of blue square to the center, if it's same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have same using Chrome. This fixes it:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="module">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100"> 
</div>
</div>
```

and css

```
.module
{
width:200px;
height:200px;
background:blue;
color:#fff;
padding:10px;
}

.container:hover .module
{
-webkit-transform-origin:50% 50%;
-webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 0.08s;
-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
-webkit-transform:perspective(800px) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) translateZ(-20px);

}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: This won't work if I have more than 1 module in the container though? And I don't want to add an extra `div` element per `module` just for styling

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue got to do with the negative z value since changing it to `translateZ(20px);` works fine. A fix, if you don’t want to use an extra `div` could be to add `-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;` to the `body`.

Here's an updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nHaHw/17/)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

I put it into a container div. Applied hover to the container and set the pointer-events on .module to none. Removed unnecessary stuff. You can still add -webkit- to some of those things if you need to. It didn't seem necessary by me.

Notice I moved the transition outside of the hover code
`

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    perspective: 800px;
}

.module {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: blue;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    pointer-events: none; 
    transition: transform 0.08s;
}

.container:hover .module {
    transform: translateZ(-20px);
}
```

```html
        <div class="container">
            <div class="module">
                sdfsdf
                <br />
                <br />
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" />
            </div>​
        </div>
```

`